# printing an array of arrays java

Tags: java, arrays

Firstly apologies if this is really simple to solve, I am still learning.
I have an ArrayList of arrays String[][] and I am trying to print them all out.
when i use the code below it only prints the same board multiple times and not every board that is in the list, i cant see where i am going wrong.

unless it is overwriting everytime?

```
for (int i = 0; i < Player.getBoardsAll().size(); i++) {
    TextIO.putln();
    TextIO.put("   ");

    for (char a = 'A'; a < 'A' + Board.getColumns(); a++) {
        TextIO.put(a, 4);
    }

    TextIO.putln();
    TextIO.putln();

    for (int r = 0; r < Board.getRows(); r++) {
        TextIO.putf("%-3d", r+1);

        for (int c = 0; c < Board.getColumns(); c++) {
            TextIO.put(Player.getBoardsAll(i)[r][c], 4);
        }

        TextIO.putln();
        TextIO.putln();
    }
}
```

This is what is calling and setting the above:

```
private static ArrayList<String[][]> boardsAll = new ArrayList<String[][]>();

public static void setBoardsAll(String[][] input) {
    boardsAll.add(input);
}

public static String[][] getBoardsAll(int location) {
    return Player.boardsAll.get(location);
}

public static ArrayList<String[][]> getBoardsAll() {
    return boardsAll;
}
```

Comment: I suspect you aren't loading the list correctly. have you tried a debugger?

Comment: You have forgot a closing bracket on your outer loop.

Comment: @BurakTutanlar added the closing bracket in the edit. Perhaps you have this error in your original code too, but I guess you would have got a compiler error in that case.

Comment: Have you tried filling your array w/o using TextIO?

Comment: just added my getters and setters, when i run the full code it is correct with how many times it has added a String[][] to the ArrayList but just prints the last one every time.

Comment: You need not apologize. We are all here to learn and help fellow learners.

Answer (score 0):

If it is always printing the same boards, then maybe you inserted the same board multiple times into the ArrayList. For example, did you do something like that:

```
String[][] board = new String[x][y];
// you inserted some data into board
setBoardsAll(board); // you added the board
// you cleared and/or re-inserted new data to
// the same board without creating another 2D array.
setBoardsAll(board);
```

If you do this, you will have an ArrayList with multiple pointers of the same 2D array. If this is the problem, you must create another array for every board. Let's say you created the first board and added it to the ArrayList. Then, if you edit the first board, first item in the ArrayList will be edited also, because both of they are pointing to the same array.

Comment: that makes sense and I think is what has happened. I thought if i used `boardsAll.add()` it would write that state into its array. so what would be the best way to save the state of each array? i do not want to have to create lots of individual arrays?

Comment: It seems like you have to. Do you have lots of individual boards? Do you represent a board with a 2D array? If the rows and columns are constant, then 2D array is good. If you need lots of individual 2D arrays, you need to create lots of individual arrays.

Comment: thanks, i think i know roughly what i need to do now.

Comment: I am writing code for the Knights Tour problem. What i want to do is print out all the board states at the end of the game and so was trying to add the current board states to an arraylist after every move and then just print the array of arrays at the end to show to the player.

Comment: Maybe you can just save the moves instead of whole board. Like diff.